# Uninstall MySQL in Ubuntu 

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, python

I just tried to remove the MySQL client by using

```
apt-get remove mysql-client-5.1
```

but an error comes out:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnet-daemon-perl libhtml-template-perl libdbi-perl mysql-client-core-5.1
  libdbd-mysql-perl libplrpc-perl mysql-server-core-5.1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-client-5.1 mysql-server-5.1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 34.8MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 29745 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server-5.1 ...
mysql stop/waiting
Removing mysql-client-5.1 ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up python-setuptools (0.6.10-4ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-setuptools.postinst: 10: pycentral: not found
dpkg: error processing python-setuptools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-setuptools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I complete the deletion?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `pycentral` is - for whatever reason - not installed on your system although python-setuptools depends on it.

```
apt-get install -y python-central
apt-get remove -y mysql-client-5.1
```

should fix the problem and remove MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to MySQL. You have packages that didn't finish configuring from the last time you ran `apt-get`. The issue you're having is that python is not correctly installed. Install pycentral with `apt-get install pycentral` and then that should fix your problems.

Answer (score 0):

The `-f` switch of apt-get will try to resolve problems.

```
apt-get -f install
```

From: http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/48910 :

> Run apt-get -f install or apt-get -f remove without specifying a package, to force completion of package installations.